# convert java bytes to c# bytes (serializing issue )

Tags: c#, java, android, .net, serialization

in the following I tried to make some sort of magi-ration between Java serialize text file stored in amazon to c# deserialize object. my idea is to convert signed bytes in Java to Unsigned bytes in .net ! but Unfortunately it doesn't work ! does it valid idea ? how could I solve that ?

```
using (Stream amazonStream = getObjRespone.ResponseStream)
{   
    List<sbyte> buffer = new List<sbyte>();
    int onebyte = 0;
    while (onebyte != -1)
    {
        onebyte = amazonStream.ReadByte();
        if (onebyte != -1)
            buffer.Add((sbyte)onebyte);
    }
    byte[] dest = Array.ConvertAll(buffer.ToArray(), item => (byte)item);
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(dest);
     object obj=  binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
    //byte[] b=  (byte[]) buf.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Cross-platform serialization??? Forget it! The sign of bytes is pretty pointless here.

Comment: Specifically, what isn't working? What are you seeing that indicates to you that it's not working.

Comment: I'm not sure how possible this is with standard serialization methods, but I have done serialization by hand before by making up a storage system and writing to a file using the RandomAccessFile class and then reading from it and rebuilding.

Answer (score 2):

use `protobuf` for this purpose, or other some cross-platform serilization (xml, json)

Comment: I was just about to post this. Protobuf and Protobuf-net should serve his purpose just fine.

Comment: Yes this is valid if I use this format in the tow side (Java, C#), but I have already serialized data using Java serializing without standard format !